# Mysql do not update if row does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a web app that lets you send money to other people (like paypal) for an University project.

For the send money webpage there's a form where an user can choose the money receiver's ID and the amount to send.

The system works with these queries:

```
         SET @moneytosend= ? ; //amount to send
         START TRANSACTION;
         UPDATE users SET balance= balance- @moneytosend WHERE id = ?; //sender's ID
         UPDATE users SET balance= balance+ @moneytosend WHERE id = ?; //receiver's ID
         COMMIT WORK;
```

The problem is when the user inserts a non existing ID and the query is still executed, effectively removing money from the sender.

I'm sorry if my english is not perfect, and sorry again if there are any formatting errors.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the transaction will ensure that all requests are successful in order to execute properly, isn't it so?

Comment: *"If I am not wrong, the transaction will ensure that all requests are successful in order to execute properly, isn't it so?"* indeed @HichemBOUSSETTA which means `UPDATE users SET balance= balance+ @moneytosend WHERE id = 1000000` is a successfull request even when the user id does not exists right?

Comment: Hi @raymond, I didn't get the point. I am not expert in database transactions but interested in the subject. My knowledge was that transactions guarantee data integrity when executing a series of request and perform auto-rollback in case of failure. But this only theoretical and I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Also there should be a check in there that the sender also has that amount off money right?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to check that the users exist in the `update` queries:

```
UPDATE users JOIN
       (SELECT ? as sender_id, ? as receiver_id
       ) uu
       ON u.id IN (uu.sender_id, uu.receiver_id)
    SET balance = balance + (CASE WHEN u.id = uu.receiver_id THEN @moneytosend ELSE - @moneytosend)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.id = uu.sender_id) AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u2 WHERE u2.id = uu.receiver_id);
```

This logic combines the queries into a single query and still allows you to input only two parameters.

Comment: @superleo98 i also would include the `@moneytosend` in the deliverd table `SELECT ? as sender_id, ? as receiver_id`, using a MySQL user variable is bit over the top, also if you need to use more updates in the same session and you forget the reset the `@moneytosend` all update queries will run with that value..Using a fixed moneytosend in query feels safer to use.`SELECT ? as sender_id, ? as receiver_id, ? as moneytosend`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused in the 1st update statement and it can be solved by adding `EXISTS` as a condition:

```
update users
set balance = balance - @moneytosend
where 
  balance >= @moneytosend 
  and
  id = ? <-- sender id
  and 
  exists (
    select 1 from (select * from users where id = ? <-- receiver id
  ) t);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/94UZWizuw96knJ8iFcuwNn/3) 
As suggested by Raymond Nijland, do an extra check so that balance does not get a negative value.

Comment: This will make money from nothing see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/94UZWizuw96knJ8iFcuwNn/2) , i hope you do this to mine bank account

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you mean the balance check if > 0?

Comment: it was more meant those both query are a bit error prone for allow that much variables in it's extra chance it could go wrong, Murphys law right.. And indeed there isn't also a balance check in there.

Comment: I agree but the OP's question is: *The problem is when the user inserts a non existing ID and the query is still executed*